# Disk Drive properties read via WMI

Tags: registry, wmi, hard-drive, disk

I am using WMI to query some properties disk drive. Does WMI read this information from the Drive itself or does it query the registry? How do I read the properties directly from the drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Win32_LogicalDisk Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173.aspx) must query the actual drive. I use it in powershell to show drive usage, which is not contained in the registry.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be a single source. If a property of a WMi class has the MappingStrings qualifier, you can find the source of the property there. For example:

Win32_LogicalDisk.VolumeName 
- Win32API|File System Functions|GetVolumeInformation

Win32_LogicalDisk.MediaType 
- Win32API|Device Input and Output Functions|DeviceIoControl

Win32_LogicalDisk.NumberOfBlocks 
- MIB.IETF|HOST-RESOURCES-MIB.hrStorageSize

So it seems that it is mostly Win32 API and [MIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379157(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

WMI queries the drive directly. In particular, the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(VS.85).aspx) and [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394173(VS.85).aspx) classes will query various properties about the drive. DiskDrive queries physical properties and configurations, whereas LogicalDisk queries volumes and partitions on the drive itself (like C:, etc). Not all WMI properties will be set for a particular drive; the drive may not support certain ones.

[Scriptomatic](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=09dfc342-648b-4119-b7eb-783b0f7d1178&displaylang=en), a Microsoft utility, can write up a quick script to pull all the properties for each class if you wanted to check it out, along with anything else WMI-related you might wish for. And it'll even do it in Perl!